# Module (all about module development)

Tags: module

i need resources, manuals about module development, and etc... give me please links, i want develop modules in magento, but magento tutorial very small, let me know about this info

Thanks

Comment: This site is for technical questions, links are not reliable because they can become obsolete or the content can change. There is plenty of information on Google. If you have a specific question about something you've encountered when building a module, that would be appropriate to post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of information. But if you need general information and only for developing modules - I recommend you to start with this - http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf .